# Why Scala's foldLeft has lower performance than iterating with an index on strings?

Tags: performance, scala, functional-programming

I am comparing the performance of two atoi implementations. The first is iterating on the input string getting chars using `charAt`; the second is using `foldLeft`.

```
object Atoi {
  def withRandomAccess(str: String, baze: Int): Int = {
      def process(acc: Int, place: Int, str: String, index: Int): Int = 
        if (index >= 0) process(acc + value(str.charAt(index)) * place, place * baze, str, index-1) else acc
      process(0, 1, str, str.length - 1)
    }

  def withFoldLeft(str: String, base: Int): Int = (0/:str) (_ * base + value(_))

  def value(c: Char): Int = { /* omitted for clarity */ }

  def symbol(i: Int): Char = { /* omitted for clarity */ }
}
```

The `foldLeft` version is 2x to 4x slower (the complete benchmark code is [here](https://gist.github.com/1083157)). I didn't expect this. Do you know why? Is Scala converting the string to a `List` before processing it? Do you have a hint on how to boost `foldLeft` performance on strings?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue is nothing to do with inlining, it is to do with the **boxing/unboxing** of `Char`s that is taking place when you use the `foldLeft`.

You get `foldLeft` on `String` by an implicit conversion to a `StringOps`, which is not specialized. Each `char` in the String has to be boxed into a `java.lang.Character` in order to be passed into the `Function2` (argument to `foldLeft`), then unboxed (much cheaper) to be passed into the `value` method within the function body, *then boxed again* to be fed into the next iteration of the fold.

The boxing involves the overhead of creating objects and subsequently garbage-collecting them.

---

In terms of avoiding boxing, there follows a brief and important point:

- **you shouldn't attempt to avoid boxing**, with a probability of almost 1.

*(That is to say, unless you have identified a* specific and unacceptable *performance degradation which can be attributed to boxing, then you should not worry about it.)*

If you are sure that there is an issue which you need to address, avoid the collections and `for`-comprehensions (which use `foreach` and `flatMap` under hood). If you are using a loop, use `while`.

Comment: +1, and this is one of the [many](http://www.nescala.org/2011/#performance-considerations) performance considerations when using Scala. (Syntactic) sugar really is fattening :)

Comment: I wonder to what extent specialization could be introduced to fix this type of problem.

Comment: @Kipton - specialisation will only solve this when the collections library is specialised, which is a non-trivial undertaking

Comment: How can I modify my code to avoid the unnecessary boxing/unboxing?

Comment: @Chaker - the first point I'd like to make is that you shouldn't, with a probability of *almost* 1. That is to say, **unless** you have identified a *specific and unacceptable performance degradation* which can be attributed to boxing, then you should not worry about it. If you are sure that there is an issue which you need to address, avoid the collections and for-comprehensions (which use `foreach` and `flatMap` under hood). If you are using a loop, use `while`